Why does adding a filter on sampled users drastically change my query results in Presto SQL?
Check out the following query
WITH sampled_users AS (
    SELECT
        a.user_id
    FROM table1 a
    JOIN table2 b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    WHERE
        a.date='2024-05-29'
        AND b.date='2024-05-29'
        AND b.experiment = 'experiment_name'
        AND sampling_function(CAST(a.user_id AS VARCHAR)) <= 0.00001
        AND b.condition = 'control'
),
exploded_historical_users_clusters AS (
    SELECT
        a.user_id,
        c.cluster_id
    FROM table1 a
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a.cluster_ids) AS c (cluster_id)
    JOIN sampled_users s
    ON a.user_id = s.user_id
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t3.user_id) AS distinct_user_count,
    COUNT(*) AS total_rows
FROM table3 t3
LEFT JOIN exploded_historical_users_clusters t2
ON t3.user_id = t2.user_id
AND t3.cluster_id = t2.cluster_id
WHERE
    t3.date = '2024-05-29'
    AND t3.taxonomy = 'taxonomy_level_3'
    AND t3.version = 'version_1'
    AND t3.surface = 'surface_value'
    AND t3.count > 0
    AND t2.cluster_id IS NULL
    AND t3.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM sampled_users);

I feel the last filter AND t3.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM sampled_users) is not necessary since I am joining on t3.user_id = t2.user_id. But if I don't include it, the final user_ids are not from the sampled_users table. As another side-effect if I don't include this last line, changing the sampling_function threshold of 0.0001 seems to have no effect on the final table size.
Is this expected behavior? What am I understanding wrong?

The behavior you’re seeing is expected. The LEFT JOIN includes all records from table3 regardless of whether they are in sampled_users, and the filtering on cluster_id IS NULL ensures unmatched rows, but it doesn’t inherently restrict user_ids to those in sampled_users. Therefore, the final filter is necessary to limit the results to sampled_users.
If you want to make sure that only user_ids from sampled_users are included without the need for the subquery in the final WHERE clause, you can reframe the join to be more restrictive so instead of using LEFT JOIN, you could use an INNER JOIN which inherently ensures only matched user_ids are included, try below.
WITH sampled_users AS (
    SELECT
        a.user_id
    FROM table1 a
    JOIN table2 b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    WHERE
        a.date='2024-05-29'
        AND b.date='2024-05-29'
        AND b.experiment = 'experiment_name'
        AND sampling_function(CAST(a.user_id AS VARCHAR)) <= 0.00001
        AND b.condition = 'control'
),
exploded_historical_users_clusters AS (
    SELECT
        a.user_id,
        c.cluster_id
    FROM table1 a
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a.cluster_ids) AS c (cluster_id)
    JOIN sampled_users s
    ON a.user_id = s.user_id
)
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t3.user_id) AS distinct_user_count,
    COUNT(*) AS total_rows
FROM table3 t3
JOIN exploded_historical_users_clusters t2
ON t3.user_id = t2.user_id
AND t3.cluster_id = t2.cluster_id
WHERE
    t3.date = '2024-05-29'
    AND t3.taxonomy = 'taxonomy_level_3'
    AND t3.version = 'version_1'
    AND t3.surface = 'surface_value'
    AND t3.count > 0;

